# What does this "ordinal cipher" say?

Tags: cipher

I invented (I think) a kind of cipher! What does this message say?:

first fifthhsecondngfourth firstsecondthirdfourthfifth, fourthecoseventhd fifthsixthsecondseventheighthfourth fourthninthtentheleventhseventhtwelfth

Hint:

> this one thirdfourth mucsecond seventhafourththirdseventhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Decryption method

A couple of the "words" are easy to recognise as actual words:

> first `T`h`I`ng`S` firstsecondthirdfourthfifth, `S`eco`N`d fifthsixthsecondseventheighthfourth fourthninthtentheleventhseventhtwelfth

That means

> second = `I`, fourth = `S`, fifth = `T`, seventh = `N`

so I suspect that

> these ordinals may be letters in some "key" word (`?I?ST?N...`) and the message itself becomes
>
>  first `T`h`I`ng`S` first`I`third``` S``T ```, `S`eco`N`d `T`sixth``` I``N ```eighth`S` `S`ninthtentheleventh`N`twelfth

### Solution

It's now clear that the message is

> FIRST THINGS FIRST, SECOND THINGS SECOND

so the ordinals are

> first = `F`, second = `I`, third = `R`, fourth = `S`, fifth = `T`, sixth = `H`, seventh = `N`, eighth = `G`, ninth = `E`, tenth = `C`, eleventh = `O`, twelfth = `D`

and the system is

> to generate ordinals from the letters of the plaintext itself and then apply them to encrypt it to the ciphertext.

This is also consistent with the hint.

Comment: Ah... I was on the right track but didn't realize that not all substitutions were uniformly applied. Nice solve!